# Using #ifndef breaks node-gyp module

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node-gyp, ifndef

I'm writing a `node.js` module using `C++` and `node-gyp` but when I fix all the errors, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085231/cant-find-node-gyp-module) question, which included getting rid of redundant declarations by adding

```
#ifndef BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION
```

and

```
#endif
```

to my files. Then I get the error

```
module.js:356
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                               ^
Error: Symbol graph_module not found.
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/home/project/test.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

but when I remove them everything works fine, instead I just get compiler warnings like

```
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/graph/graph/addon.o
../graph/addon.cc:2:9: warning: 'BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' macro redefined
#define BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION
```

I don't get why this would be, And I would like to get rid of the compiler warnings if possible. Have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have either forgotten to use the NODE_MODULE macro or the name for your module in the binding.gyp does not match what is used in the NODE_MODULE

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the compiler warnings, try replacing

```
#define BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION
```

with

```
#define BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION 1
```